# Which items have the highest enchantment values?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I have a full set of Glass armor, a spell for Summon Gold Saint and plenty of Grand Soul gems. I was planning on create a "super-suit" with different constant effect such as Fortify Speed, Fortify Agility, Sanctuary, Fortify Strenght, Night Eye and Restore Health. However the enchantment values of the glass pieces are too low. I even downloaded a mod that increases the enchantment values for 10 times and still is too low, the best I could create was a couple of Expensive rings with Night Eye 25 points and Restore Health 10 to 15 points. I tried enchanting with Chamaleon and I can create a full suit with 100% but it will feel like cheating...

Looks like, after all my efforts, I can't create my dreamed overpowered armor for my assassin-thief character, so I'd like to know which items have the highest enchantment values? So far I can tell Expensive Rings. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good magic armor needs to be found or earned. For example Ebony Mail is awesome, but if you could easily make a better armor what would be the point in getting it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Armor's actually pretty lousy for enchanting.  Most of the light and medium armor tops out at around 20 points of enchantment.  If you want to enchant light armor, the best pieces are glass cuirass (12 points), Telvanni cephalopod helm (an astonishing 100 points), glass greaves (10 points), glass boots (10 points), glass or chitin bracers (10 points each), and a glass tower shield (45 points).  Pauldrons are uniformly bad (no more than 1.5 points each).

The best generic armor options without regard to weight are the Daedric Cuirass (60 points, heavy), Telvanni Cephalopod Helm (100 points, light), Imperial Chain Pauldrons (7 points each, heavy), glass greaves (10 points, light), Daedric Boots (26.3, heavy), Daedric Gauntlets (60 points each, heavy), and the Daedric Tower Shield (225 points, heavy).

If you want to attach powerful enchantments to ordinary wearable items, though, you want to focus on clothing.  An exquisite shirt (60 points), exquisite pants (60), exquisite skirt (60, and yes, you can wear it with pants), exquisite shoes (40 points), an exquisite robe (40), an exquisite belt (40), extravagant gloves (20 points each, but mutually exclusive with gauntlets or bracers), two exquisite rings (120 points each), and an exquisite amulet (120 points again) will give you far more enchanting opportunities than any armor.

(Source: [Ultimate Elder Scrolls Pages, items listing](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Items))

Comment: So clothing is the way, thanks, I guess I'll use them for roleplaying as a Vampire.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Tribunal, Bloodmoon, and free Helm of Tohan expansion from Bethesda.com you can go after the Helm of Tohan (150 points), Nordic Skaal Left and Right Pauldrons/Left Adamantium Pauldron (10 points), Ebony Scimitar (80 Points) for the weapon, or the Ebony Staff (90 points).